# sylenium returns a promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to build a web scraper. The goal is to download the pdf that can be accessed by a series of links on a webpage. Currently, I am trying to retrieve the URLs directing to the pdf files, so I would be able to insert them in e.g. node download helper (or maybe wget). Ideally, I would have an array of the different links that I can then iterate through.

Currently, the function looks like this.

```
function scrape(){
driver.get('https://examplelink.com/pagewheretofindthedifferentlinks')
.then(function(){ 
    return links = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText('ABCD.')); //all the links contain the same pattern lets say 'ABCD.BLABLA.BLABLA'
})
.then(function(links){
    console.log(links[0].getAttribute('href'))
})}
```

For one or another reason this returns:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I have tried a lot of different forms of the async await... but nothing seems to work.

I have also tried to click the link and then use driver.getCurrentUrl() but this just returns the URL of the original page ('https://xxx.be/xxx') and not the URL of the tabs that are opened, which would lead me to implement a function that the driver switches between the different tabs...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean it does *log* a promise? Then use `.then(function(links){ return links[0].getAttribute('href'); }).then(function(href) { console.log(href); })` instead.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried your solution and this works for the links[0] element. If I try however a for loop for all the web elements in the links array, it keeps returning a promise. I tried a different possibility where the driver waits for the getAttribute('href'). This again works for one single link, but when iterating through the hrefArray, it does not seem to work and keeps returning a [object Promise] for each link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the way I got it currently working:

```
//function for finding hrefs
function findHref(array, input){
          
   var href = driver.wait(array[input].getAttribute('href'))
   return href;
}

//delete all cookies
//driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

//navigate findlinks
function scrape(){
   console.log('Starting scrape process')
   driver.get('https://blabla.com/blabla')
   .then(function(){
       return links = driver.findElements(By.tagName('a'));
   })
   .then(function(links){
       for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
           findHref(links, i)
           .then(function(href){
               console.log("This is link:" + href)
           })
       }

   })
}
```